# Is there any way to cure the confusion status inflicted by Malfestio?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

Malfestio can inflict a status with yellow vapors he produces. When hit by them your controls are all reversed for a short period (i.e. holding left on the analog stick will move you right). I know this goes away on it's own, and that getting hit gets rid of it too, but is there a way to end the status early without taking damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eating a Bitterbug will cure confusion.

Source: The in-game monster information, in the hunter notes

Comment: @Wipqozn I don't blame you for not reading them; usually they don't have any useful information. They've changed that in generations though, as those notes now tell you what items you'll want to bring